# Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, fluentvalidation

I want to add the FluentValidation Nuget package in my asp.net core app through Nuget Package Manager.While adding I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
>   Project Name -> FluentValidation.AspNetCore 7.6.103 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
>   2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common
>   (>= 2.8.0)   Project Name ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils 2.0.0 ->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 2.3.1 ->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common 2.3.1 ->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 2.3.1).

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just faced the same issue.
Unfortunately, this package refers to .net core 2.1, which is incompatible with 2.0.

Here's how I managed to resolve this issue:

- Install the 2.1 SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

- Follow migration instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and was upgrading to 2.1, but for some reason I needed to manually upgrade my Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common package from 2.8.0 to 2.8.2

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -Version 2.8.2
```

Comment: yes thank you. After running this command, I was able to upgrade to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, replacing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Answer (score 3):

If you're project is running under .NET Core 3.1 LTS
Then please install the following package into your targeted project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -Version 3.6.0
```

And then

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces -Version 3.6.0
```

This will resolve your problem.